# Appending values to start in sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

I wanted to append   360 10056 to my values below.I have large set of values  .If there is any plugin in sublime?

```
    176810  f0101bde-2f34-41d5-bbaa-b20082e6c6ec  07F2BBA0-205A-47B0-9AD5-9CBFCFFB6E27.pdf
    176869  159b0eb7-0e7f-4a99-80ea-9ee806d9b72f  48E3E25C-5515-46D9-A282-9A69549F6E6F.pdf
    176890  dc86a5c2-8db3-4c55-979e-86d1da0e5e4c  642635A6-C8D4-4E3A-9420-7416014FFBF8.pdf
    176891  50f98b21-24e7-4ffa-a4b2-5670ad13961f  644287AB-39EB-4BFE-97F2-AB6C5AC574D2.pdf
    176892  5ed801ad-46b6-4836-83c8-46c2d1471790  64F627C2-5980-4540-AC9C-B90A2B72B091.pdf
    176912  408d59c9-23bd-43c3-8753-d8d46be6a53b  78EB394A-EF22-4D28-AE81-9522903EC9D6.pdf
    176936  6af61123-dc7b-4484-b194-3cab979835c8  8BB6904C-B019-4508-AC05-AAE4C274BB3C.pdf
    176943  13941d28-625f-4d55-8ce4-4d90f7c8e31f  93123A36-CB67-4CE6-B1E5-923307FCD285.pdf
```

to

```
360 10056 176810  f0101bde-2f34-41d5-bbaa-b20082e6c6ec  07F2BBA0-205A-47B0-5AD5-9CBFPFFB6E27.pdf
360 10056 176869  159b0eb7-0e7f-4a99-80ea-9ee806d9b72f  48E3E25C-5515-46D9-A282-9A69549M6E6F.pdf
360 10056 176890  dc86a5c2-8db3-4c55-979e-86d1da0e5e4c  642635A6-C8D4-4E3A-9420-741601TFFBF8.pdf
360 10056 176891  50f98b21-24e7-4ffa-a4b2-5670ad13961f  644287AB-39EB-4BFE-97F2-AB6C5AK574D2.pdf
360 10056 176892  5ed801ad-46b6-4836-83c8-46c2d1471790  64F627C2-5980-4540-AC9C-B90A2BH2B091.pdf
360 10056 176912  408d59c9-23bd-43c3-8753-d8d46be6a53b  78EB394A-EF22-4D28-AE81-9522903EC9D6.pdf
360 10056 176936  6af61123-dc7b-4484-b194-3cab979835c8  8BB6904C-B019-4508-AC05-AAE4C2H4BB3C.pdf
360 10056 176943  13941d28-625f-4d55-8ce4-4d90f7c8e31f  93123A36-CB67-4CE6-B1E5-923307PCD285.pdf
```

Comment: You could try [selecting the column](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html) before the first text and type "360 10056"

Comment: I would use the Find/Replace functionality; open the panel, make sure `regex` is turned on, then search for `^` (start of the line) and enter your text as the replacement, and then hit the `Replace All` button. Depending on your data you may need to tweak the regex as appropriate.

Comment: `Ctrl+a` then `ctrl+shift+l` then press left arrow key. Now you can write anything before every line. Make sure you don't have any gaps between any lines.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that i could think of, is

1. copy 1 line of the data you want
   360 10056
2. Select the 176 at the beggining(just those numbers)
3. And press CTRL + D, that will select all ocurrencies of the 176.
4. After you have the desired amount selected you just press left in the keyboard and you will have a lot of duplicated cursors.
5. Paste your copied data and that will paste that line of code into all the lines you got there.

Option 2:

I found this package called paste as column that might be of help.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Paste%20as%20Column